# Algorithm to figure out whether a given set of characters covers a given set of words

Tags: algorithm, bitmap

I came across the following algorithms problem(src: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=15029889)

Problem:
c = ‘a’
w = “apple”
c covers w, iff w contains c.
c_set = {‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘g’}
w_set = {‘apple’, ‘ibm’, ‘cisco’, ‘google’}
c_set covers w_set, iff every w in w_set is covered by some c in c_set.
Given c_set and w_set, Whether w_set is covered by c_set?
Follow up: if w_set is fixed say a book, how to determine whether a c_set covers this w_set?

One possible solution is:
If we use 26bits(1 bit for each character) to represent each word in w_set,
and then also form a similar bitmask for c_set, a solution to check coverage
would be to do "c_set_bitmask & word_i_bitmask". If this is non-zero for each
word, then we have covered every word.

My question is, can we do anything better than this, given that
the w_set is static e.g. a book.

Comment: What is meant by w_set being fixed or static?

Comment: It means that since it won't change, we can do some preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is of O(nlogk) ~ O(n) where n = total number of 'letters' in w_set and k = number of letters in c_set. max(k) = 26. Hence we can assume k is constant.

The algorithm seems naïve but I can't see any solution better than O(n) because in any algorithm you will atleast need to scan all the letters in w_set to check whether they are present in c_set.

Sort c_set lexicographically.  (O(klogk)) ~ constant
Scan each word in w and perform binary search for the letters in c_set. (O(nlogk)) ~ O(n).